# Need tot. no of employees count of a company which is establised after 1990

Tags: sql, join, group-by, where-clause, having

[image]Two tables with their data which I have created.

```
select c.name,e.year,c.branch,c.employees from company as c 
join Established as e on c.name=e.name;

select c.name,sum(c.employees),e.year from company as c 
join Established as e on c.name=e.name where e.year=1990 group by c.Name
```

It's working correctly, But when I use-

```
select c.name,sum(c.employees),e.year from company as c 
join Established as e on c.name=e.name 
group by c.Name having e.year=1990
```

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
> clause and contains nonaggregated column 'joins.e.year' which is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
select c.name,sum(c.employees),e.year from company as c 
join Established as e on c.name=e.name 
group by c.Name having e.year\>1990;

select c.name,sum(c.employees),e.year from company as c 
join Established as e on c.name=e.name 
group by c.Name having e.year\>1990 LIMIT 0, 1000
```

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
> clause and contains nonaggregated column 'joins.e.year' which is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by 0.000 sec

Comment: Data should be provided as formatted text tables, not image, and/or DDL code.

Comment: Either use WHERE instead of HAVING (WHERE clause goes before GROUP BY) and don't SELECT year or put year in the GROUP BY as well.

Comment: I find it odd that the first GROUP BY query worked without year in GROUP BY. If it did work, why did you change query structure? The error messages are quite explicit.

Comment: Q-Need total no of employees in a companies from the above tables which was established after 1990. Pls write a query for this question.

Comment: I would be inclined to assist if you complied with request in first comment. Did you attempt suggestion in second comment?

Comment: Yes, I got my answer. My question has been solved. Thanks for being a part of helping me out.